# How to reproduce a case where daemonset failed with no pod is ready

Tags: kubernetes

How to reproduce no pod is ready when deploying a daemonset?

I try a small example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: logging
  labels:
    app: fluentd-logging
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: fluentd
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: fluentd
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: fluentd-elasticsearch
        image: quay.io/fluentd_elasticsearch/fluentd:v2.5.2
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
```

A follow-up question is how to use field-selector to get events for daemonset error?

involvedObject.kind=Daemonset,involvedObject.name="{daemonset-name}"

Answer (score 1):

To set to a not ready pod of your DaemonSet, you can simply add a readiness probe that will never be ready.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: fluentd-logging
spec:  
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: fluentd
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: fluentd
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: fluentd-elasticsearch
        image: quay.io/fluentd_elasticsearch/fluentd:v2.5.2
        # here the readinessProbe
        readinessProbe:
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          httpGet:
            host: www.dominiochenonesiste.com
            port: 80       
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
```

To check the pod status, you can use the `kubetcl describe pod <nameofyourdaemonsetpodcreated>`

Within the output you will have:

```bash
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True
```

Hope it helps!

Cose belle!

Comment: When PodScheduled=False, it means the daemonset is not deployment successfully. Correct?

Comment: @susanna Yes, there is a problem on pod creation. It's not the same as Ready: False. a tipical case of Scheduled False (pening state) is when the image does not exists.